# How to get kendo grid dropdownchange event for MVC

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have used MVC kendo grid and I have bind the dropdown to grid. Now I have to get the dropdownchange event to populate other grid items by using dropdown selection.

```
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CountryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries).Title("Select Country");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#ddlTables").change(function () {

//You will get change event here
//Add debugger here and see
//Do your code here
});
```

```html
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CountryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Countries,new {@id = "ddlCountry"}).Title("Select Country");
```

Here is the code replace this with your code and try to do your stuff and if still facing issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an editor template as follows. 
change the column as follows

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CountryID).Title("Country").EditorTemplateName("Countries").Width(300);
```

after that create a partial view inside `views/shared/EditorTemplates` with name `Countries` as follows

```
@using System.Collections
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.DataValueField("COUNTRYNAME")
        .DataTextField("COUNTRYNAME")
        .Name("CountryID")
        .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Countries)
        .OptionLabel("Select Country")
        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .Events(e =>
        {
         e.Change("CountryChange");
       })
  )
```

After this you can write jquery as follows

```
<script>
function CountryChange()
{
 //You will get change event here
}
```

Comment: Can we make it Editor template as Dynamic? So if from any other place if I want same requirement then instead of creating new editor template we can use it Dynamic one?

Comment: @SagarShinde For every pages with country drop-down you can use it.